# Paste an Array into the last row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to paste an array into the last row of a sheet.

(The data is from an API source and I want to grab a bunch of info and add a new line at the bottom of the sheet as historical data)

I managed to piece together the correct range, but now it wants it as an integer?
(Exception: Cannot convert 'A3' to int.)
Here's the part in question:

```
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  let lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  let myA = "A" + lastRow ;
  let myZ = "L" + lastRow ;
sheet.getRange(myA, myZ).setValues(stData);
```

A simple AppendRow doesn't work either, as it only pastes [Ljava.lang.Object;@6ddc861f
in the cell instead of the actual values.

and here's the full code for reference. (except for the API ID):

```
function getST() {
  const playerID = "XXX";
  let url = "https://smartytitans.com/api/info/player/";
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let request = url + playerID;
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);
  let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  let stStats = [];
  stStats.push(data.data.level);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.gld);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.prest);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.invst);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.master);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.help);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.ascendUpg);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.bounty);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.collection);
  stStats.push(data.data.cityName);
  stStats.push(data.data.cityLevel);
  stStats.push(data.data.rankGld);


  let stData = [];
  stData.push(stStats);

  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  let lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  let myA = "A" + lastRow ;
  let myZ = "L" + lastRow ;
sheet.getRange(myA, myZ).setValues(stData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method expects a 1D array but `stData` contains a 2D array. To make it work, use `stStats`, like this:

```
  ///...
  stStats.push(data.data.rankGld);
  sheet.appendRow(stStats);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, stData.length, stData[0].length).setValues(stData);
```

The parameters are row, column, number of rows, number of columns

```
function getST() {
  const playerID = "XXX";
  let url = "https://smartytitans.com/api/info/player/";
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let request = url + playerID;
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);
  let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  let stStats = [];
  stStats.push(data.data.level);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.gld);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.prest);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.invst);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.master);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.help);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.ascendUpg);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.bounty);
  stStats.push(data.data.stats.collection);
  stStats.push(data.data.cityName);
  stStats.push(data.data.cityLevel);
  stStats.push(data.data.rankGld);
  let stData = [];
  stData.push(stStats);
  sheet.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,stData.length,stData[0].length).setValues(stData);
}
```

This will allow you to paste more than one row.  appendRow can be very slow if you have lots of rows in your data